# How to get the annotations of an interfaces implementation class

Tags: java, annotations, code-injection

I want a class **PersonCollector** to inject a field by specific classes which have the annotation **PersonResolver**. **PersonCollector** checks if the annotated class has a annotation value which equals the **PersonCollector.personType** field. If it complies, the logic will add the class which implements owns this annotation and assigns it to the **PersonCollector.personByType** field.

My problem here is, that I have an Interface **Person** and two implementing classes **CoolPerson** & **UncoolPerson** both annotated with the **@PersonResolver** annotation and a value which specifies their type with the Enum **PersonType**.

The only way to look for ALL implementations which hold the specific interface is to call on **Person** i.e. `Person.class.getAnnotations()`. This unfortunately only yields the annotations which are declared on the Person interface.

That is not what I actually want. I would love a list of all *implementations* of **Person** who own the Annotation - not Person itself.

Here is the pseudo/scratch code for what I want to achieve:

**@PersonResolver**

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PersonResolver {
  PersonType value();
}
```

**Both implementations**

```
@PersonResolver(PersonType.COOL)
public class CoolPerson implements Person {
  // implementation
}

@PersonResolver(PersonType.UNCOOL)
public class UncoolPerson implements Person {
  // implementation
}
```

**PersonCollector**

```
public class PersonCollector {
  private PersonType personType;
  private Person personByType;

  public PersonCollector(PersonType personType) {
    this.personType = personType; // PersonType.COOL

    Annotation[] annotations = Person.class.getDeclaredAnnotation(PersonResolver.class);

    // What I'd like to get are ALL classes that implement the "Person" interface
    // and have the "PersonResolver" Annotation.

    // PseudoCode!
    if (annotations[0].value == personType) {
      this.personByType = annotations[0].getClassThatImplementsMe(); // CoolPerson instance is assigned to the field
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library such as [`Reflections`](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) that will scan the classpath for types annotated with `PersonResolver`.  For example, the following code will return a set of `java.lang.Class`es annotated with `@PersonResolver`, and whose `value()` attribute equals `personType`.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(("com.myproject"));
Set<Class<?>> annotated = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(PersonResolver.class)
        .stream()
        .filter(c -> c.getAnnotation(PersonResolver.class).value() == personType)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```